# Specify Index Range on Train Split SciKit-Learn

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, scikit-learn

I am trying to wrap my head around the concept of using the last 30% of the entries in the dataset as the test samples. Nothing Random (Intentional). Is this possible?

Split dataset into train / test:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3,random_state=0)
```

Is it possible to explicitly control the split in such a manner that the test split only selects entries from the end of the dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will achieve your goal if you substitute the line:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3,random_state=0)
```

with:

```
idx_train = int((1-.3)* x.shape[0]) # train is (1-.3) of your data
x_train = x[:idx_train,:]
x_test = x[idx_train:, :]
y_train = y[:idx_train]
y_test = y[idx_train:]
```

Comment: Tried it and it seems to be giving me the desired split. You've saved me an entire day!